# How to subtract values in one column based on values in another column

Tags: pandas

I am trying to manipulate a pandas DataFrame that has 2 columns, `Type` and `Value`:

```
type    value
-------------
  1     100
  2       1
  3       1
  4       1
  1     300
  2       1
  3       1  
  4       1
  1     500
  2       1
  3       1
  4     700
```

I want to create a new column, difference, which would be the product of subtracting the value from the the previous value, only for type == 1. (so 300-100, 500-300, 700-500)

One option is by coping the selected celes to a new df

```
new = df[df['type'].isin(['1'])]
```

do the subtraction and join the dfs again. but is there a better way of doing with out having to move to a new df?

Comment: 700 is type 4 ...

Comment: is this what you are looking for? `df['new_column'] = df.loc[df.type == 1].diff().value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df['newcol'] = df.loc[df['type'] == 1, 'value'].diff()
```

Output:

```
    type  value  newcol
0      1    100     NaN
1      2      1     NaN
2      3      1     NaN
3      4      1     NaN
4      1    300   200.0
5      2      1     NaN
6      3      1     NaN
7      4      1     NaN
8      1    500   200.0
9      2      1     NaN
10     3      1     NaN
11     4    700     NaN
```